# getting error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting following error stack while launching chrome browser through selenium. Chrome version is 65.

```
    [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
    ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7) on port 40188
    Only local connections are allowed.
    org.testng.TestNGException: 
    Cannot instantiate class ipd.project.analytics.BarChart
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:31)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:410)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:323)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:191)
        at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:99)
        at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:85)
        at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:77)
        at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:42)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:423)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:250)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:220)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:169)
newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.streamW3CProtocolParameters(ProtocolHandshake.java:284)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:149)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
        at ipd.Base.setupChromeDriver(Base.java:143)
        at ipd.Base.<init>(Base.java:61)
        at ipd.project.analytics.BarChart.<init>(BarChart.java:28)
        ... 30 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:559)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:167)
            ... 41 more
```

I tried adding following dependency in pom.xml but it did not help:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Clean, build project also did not help.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trials?

Comment: Fixed, upgraded to selenium standalone server 3.11.

Comment: what was the exact issue that was fixed in this version?

Comment: It was 3.11.0 version